# In blender how can I programmatically insert a new grease pencil object (svg) at coordinates/rotation

Tags: python, blender

I'm trying to create and place a series of sketches from a tablet to a blender file. I know where they should go in 3d-space. I am trying to construct a python script to input a file name and coordinates then place thing at location.

From some code I found.. I think this is very close. The script leaves off at allowing the user to draw. Instead I want to import a file.

```
import bpy
context = bpy.context
space = context.space_data

# Create material for grease pencil
if "Bright Material" in bpy.data.materials.keys():
    gp_mat = bpy.data.materials["Bright Material"]
else:
    gp_mat = bpy.data.materials.new("Bright Material")

if not gp_mat.is_grease_pencil:
    bpy.data.materials.create_gpencil_data(gp_mat)
    gp_mat.grease_pencil.color = (1, 0, 0.818649, 1)

# Add grease pencil object
gp_data = bpy.data.grease_pencils.new("Bright Pencil")
gp_ob = bpy.data.objects.new("Bright Pencil", gp_data)
context.scene.collection.objects.link(gp_ob)
if space.local_view:
    gp_ob.local_view_set(space, True)

for ob in context.selected_objects:
    ob.select_set(False)
gp_ob.select_set(True)
context.view_layer.objects.active = gp_ob
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='PAINT_GPENCIL')

# Assign the material to the grease pencil for drawing
gp_data.materials.append(gp_mat)
```

next instead of `bpy.ops.gpencil.draw(wait_for_input=False)`

can I do something like `bpy.context.image_paint_object`
or `bpy.ops.object.load_reference_image`

or otherwise import an SVG image and set the rotation of it? can I add a frame number for animation?

Comment: do I need a material at all? Am I misunderstanding greasepencil entirely?